# Node.JS Looking for an alternative to socket.IO

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been testing Node.JS and Socket.IO for a couple of days. I'm interested in a real-time application that's why I'm testing Socket.IO, problem is I found many problems on several browsers. Chrome always works but IE and Firefox only some times.

My question is, is there a way to push information from the server to the client without sockets (socket.io)? I don't want to set an interval in the client and check if something changes on the server side every "n" seconds.

Comment: Socket.io !== websockets, there are other websocket libraries for node, like websocket-node https://github.com/Worlize/WebSocket-Node/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Socket.IO has had some bugs recently, but they're being actively worked on, so I encourage you to check back later (it may even already be working better now, as there are commits almost every day). This is the issue you should be watching: http://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO-node/issues#issue/63

Answer (score 5):

[Faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/) is a good alternative to Socket.IO for Node.js push applications.

From the Faye website:

> Faye is an easy-to-use
>   publish-subscribe messaging system
>   based on the Bayeux protocol. It
>   provides message servers for Node.js
>   and Rack, and clients for use in Node
>   and Ruby programs and in the browser.

Answer (score 3):

You can try long-polling. It's relatively simple and it'll work in almost any browser. Check this out:

http://jsguy.com/?p=103

Hope this helps