# Realtime application - alternative for socket.io (node.js)

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I use node.js.

I am looking for an alternative for socket.io.

I need to send a private message to the user.

What is the alternative for the SOCKET.IO?

Comment: What do you need? What's the reason socket.io does not fit your needs?

Comment: I'm making a socket.io alternative using ws try it if you like https://github.com/benzmuircroft/re-connect.ws

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't really explained why you're looking for Socket.IO. If you provide more details into why Socket.IO isn't working for you then you can get a better answer. Otherwise I'll just point you to a duplicate of this question.

[Node.JS Looking for an alternative to socket.IO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911783/node-js-looking-for-an-alternative-to-socket-io)